# How to enable a bot to speak in a stage channel

Tags: discord.py

I have looked through all the documentation discord.py (Probably not very good) And I did not find how a bot can become a speaker itself in the stage channel.
All I found was just a request to become a speaker - `await request_to_speak()`

Comment: I do not think bots can join and speak in Stage Channels

Comment: They can connect to the channel as a listener so that they can speak they need to be manually given the right to speak

Comment: And I want to understand how to get a bot to give itself this right

Comment: You can give the bot the right to speak with editing the channel permissions (stage admin or whatever it's called)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `await member.edit(suppress = False)` instead of `await member.request_to_speak()`.

"suppress" parameter indicates the state of the speaker in the Stage Channel.

Here's [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/api.html?highlight=request_to_speak#discord.Member.edit)

Your welcome!